# Try-Except block - Did I do this correctly?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

We are learning exception handling.  Did I do this correctly?  Is ValueError the correct exception to use to catch strings being typed instead of numbers?  I tried to use TypeError, but it doesn't catch the exception.

Also, is there a more efficient way to catch each exception in my four inputs?  What is best practice here?

```
#Ask user for ranges. String inputs are not accepted and caught as exceptions. While loop repeats asking user for input until a float number is input.
while True:
    try:
        rangeLower = float(input("Enter your Lower range: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a number!")
    else:
        #Break the while-loop
        break
while True:
    try:
        rangeHigher = float(input("Enter your Higher range: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a number!")
    else:
        #Break the while-loop
        break
#Ask user for numbers. String inputs are not accepted and caught as exceptions. While loop repeats asking user for input until a float number is input.
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter your First number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a number!")
    else:
        #Break the while-loop
        break
while True:
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Enter your Second number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter a number!")
    else:
        #Break the while-loop
        break
```

Comment: Does it work the way you expect when you run it?

Comment: Good point.  Yes, it works as expected.  However, I am still new and have found myself running code that I thought worked as intended, yet it was still written improperly.  Anyways, it does seem to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are experiencing what is called, **WET** code Write Everything Twice, we try to write **DRY** code, i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself.

In your case what you should do is create a function called `float_input` as using your `try` `except` block and calling that for each variable assignment.

```
def float_input(msg):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            pass


range_lower = float_input('Enter your lower range: ')
...
```